# Injectivity in functions

Tags: functions, computability

Sorry, I know that it has to be a very simple problem, but I'm frustrated because of it.

Let $f,g:\mathbb{N}^3→\mathbb{N}f$:

$f(x,y,z)=3^x⋅5^y⋅7^z$ and $g(x,y,z)=3^x+5^y+7^z$
Prove that:

$1.f$ is injective but $g$ isn't.

$2.$ Prove that they aren't bijective.

EDIT: those were power, not multiplications.

EDIT 2: sorry, I'm the OP, but I don't know how to edit the question as the original poster, so it appeared as Community :(

Comment: $\;f\;$ is not injective at all: $\;f(1,2,3)=f(3,2,1)=f(2,1,3)\;$ , for example.

Comment: Are these multiplications supposed to be powers? (It was a suggested edit, but it appears to have been rejected.) In other words, should it be $f(x,y,z)=3^x 5^y 7^z$, $g(x,y,z) = 3^x+5^y+7^z$?

Comment: So we have moved from the false to the obvious!

Comment: Someone called "Comunity" decided that user347171's question must have been wrong and *changed it*...how come? My comment above and my answer below refer to the **original question** the asker asked.

Comment: With the modification, if $0\in\mathbb{N}$, then $g(1,2,1) = g(3,0,1)$. If $0\notin \mathbb{N}$, it would take a bit more work to come up with an example like this. Also, to show that neither $f$ nor $g$ are bijective, show that $2$ is not in the image of either. Finally, a hint on why $f$ is injective: what do you know about factorizations of integers in terms of prime powers?

Comment: If $0\notin \mathbb{N}$, a quick run of a fairly simple algorithm shows that $g(1,3,1) = g(3,1,2)$, and that this is one of at least 7 such points.

Answer (score 0):

Fill in details:

$$g(2,2,2)=g(1,4,1)$$

and *also*

$$f(3,5,1)=f(5,3,1)$$

Thus, neither $\;f\;$ nor $\;g\;$ are injective.

Also observe that

$$f(x,y,z)\ge 21\;,\;\;g(x,y,z)\ge 15\implies\text{neither function is surjective}$$

Comment: But $0\in \Bbb N$ :~P.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Thank you. That depends: some accept zero in the naturals, some other don't, but it never matters as the facts, even with zero in the naturals, remain the same.